# Mutator/Accessor methods for object variable declared in private

Tags: c++, object, accessor, private-members, mutators

I have a couple object variables declared in private of a class:

```
private:
a a1;
```

This overloaded operator was originally friends with this class and accessed the objects as shown bellow:

```
istream & operator >>( istream & input, class & m )
{
    input >> m.a1;
    return input;
 }
  ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const class & m )
 {
     os << m.uni;


     return os;
 }
```

When the operator is unfriended it should no longer have access to the private variables.

How would I access the two objects? Would it be the use of accessor/mutator methods that return pointers to the object?

EDIT: changed the code so it explains the question a bit more.

Comment: The same way you would access them from any other non friend function using the public accessor methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever ways there is to set the values of `a1` and `b1`.

You don't have to read directly into the private variables, you could also read values into some temporaries and then use those to modify `a1` and `b1`. Or create a brand new `Results` and assign that to `m`.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the whole accessor idea is to prevent a programmer using a class from doing something he is not supposed to do. Something that the writer of said class did not anticipate.

Private functions by definition are not for use by "everyone using the class". For example it means stuff like input validity checks are not in place - because the code calling the private function is supposed to do those checks (this aviods checking for the same cases multiple times. But run the risk of unchecked results being entered if everyone has access).

Yes, you **could** work around accessors by throwing naked pointers at the problem. Access rights are only checked by the compiler at compile time and it can not predict wich function would be at "adress XYZ" at compile time.

But if you even consdier it, you are on the wrong track. There is a damn good reason the operator was unfriended. Propably because he kept doing stuff a friend was not supposed to do.
Friends and protected are two very speicific cases where you have a private with a few select exceptions.

Do you have control of both classes? If so, why are you removing the friend state?

If you do not have control: What did you do to loose friend status? And why would you go to such lenghts to outright sabotage the proper working of the class via naked pointers?

Comment: I have access and control to the classes. The point of this was the idea behind encapsulation. So to only allow access to the private data of function in the class. The operator is meant to become a sub routine that reads in the values required in the class before passing along to the next class.

Comment: friend, protected, internal (a C#/.NET thing). They are all just "private with exception". If you are writing both classes, you can just keep it as friend. You could consider making the opeartor a simple static function. I am a bit rusty with native C++ accessors, but I think a static method getting a instance of the class as argument would be able to access private members. Or maybe write a private static function that does the work. Then make the operator a friend that just calls it.